# What exactly is $dy$ in $\mu(dy)$ when we do integration in measure theory? Question about Markov kernel

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, markov-chains

I'm reading this book on Markov chains: http://members.unine.ch/michel.benaim/perso/MarkovbookFinal120421.pdf

and on page 13, we consider a separable metric space $M$ and its Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(M)$. A *Markov kernel* is a family of probability measures $P(x,\cdot)_{x \in M}$ s.t.

(i) for any $x \in M$, $P(x,\cdot): \mathcal{B}(M) \xrightarrow{} [0,1]$ is a prob measure,
(ii) for any $G \in \mathcal{B}(M)$, the mapping that carries $x$ to $P(x, G) \in [0, 1]$ is measurable.

An operation of $P$ on a measure $\mu$ is defined as $\mu P(G) = \int_{M} \mu(dx)P(x, G)$.

The author didn't mention but it's obvious that $\mu P$ is again a measure. However, if I want to integrate something w.r.t. this measure, say a function $f$, then I write $\int f(y) \mu P (dy)$, but what does $\mu P(dy)$ mean???? $\mu P(\cdot)$ is defined for all measurable sets $G$ but not $dy$? This makes me wonder what we mean when we write $d(\mu y) = \mu(dy)$ when doing integration.

Comment: $\mu P(dy)$ is just another notation for $d(\mu  P )(y)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Then, if I want to get $\mu P(M)$ which is the measure of the whole set under measure $\mu P$, I do $\int_{M} 1(y) d\mu P(y)$, then I can't do further calculation unless I replace $d\mu P(y)$ by $\mu P(dy)$ and plug $dy$ in the definition of $\mu P$

Comment: @geetha290krm And I feel uncomfortable about this, because in measure theory when we define the integral, we only define something like $\int f d\mu$ and $\mu (dx)$ is just another notation for $d\mu = d\mu(x)$. Though unlike in Calculus, in measure theory $dx$ has no actual meaning, when we see $\mu (dx)$ we don't question its meaning because we automatically treat it as $d\mu$. But here, how can we actually work with the $dx$ notation, i.e., plug it in $\mu P$ which is not defined for the thing $dx$

Comment: @geetha290krm To put it in another way, in measure theory, when we see $\int f(x) \mu(dx)$, we don't know how to deal with $dx$ ($\mu$ not defined for $dx$) but we can just view it as $\int f d\mu$. In my question here, we cannot deal with $\mu P(dx)$ by simply writing it as $d \mu P$, but can only plug $dx$ in $\mu P(\cdot)$ which is defined for measurable sets, not $dx$